# как соединить кнопку tkinter и клавишу Enter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии клавиши Enter, нажималась и кнопка "button1" ?

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("750x750")
root.title("Код на питоне")

def window_2():
    root_2 = Tk()
    root_2.geometry("750x750")
    root_2.title("Новое окно питона")
    root_2.mainloop()

button1 = Button(bd=6, bg="#1bc98a", activebackground="#1fe39c", width=6, height=2, text="Play", command=window_2, font=("Arial 30"))
button1.place(rely=0.5, relx=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Какая связь между вашим изначальным вопросом и вопросом после правки? Почему бы просто не задать новый вопрос?

Comment: согласен...вам с 9 минусами проще новый создать...и да...прошлый с этим вопросом никак не связан. второй вопрос - уже ок. на него должны ответить

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать проверку на нажатие клавиши Enter или кнопки, например через `if KEY_ENTER == presed:` или что-то типа такого.

Answer (score 0):

Можно кейбинд привязать к функции кнопки

```html
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("750x750")
root.title("Код на питоне")

def window_2():
    root_2 = Tk()
    root_2.geometry("750x750")
    root_2.title("Новое окно питона")
    root_2.mainloop()

root.bind_all("Enter", window_2)
button1 = Button(bd=6, bg="#1bc98a", activebackground="#1fe39c",
    width=6, height=2, text="Play", command=window_2, font=("Arial 30"))
button1.place(rely=0.5, relx=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```